# Mongoose - Validate ObjectID related document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to validate as required a field "product" in Model Event. Product is ObjectID reference to Product Model.

I tried with this 2 approaches, but it is not validating

```
 product: {
    type: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Product',
      required: true
    }]
  },



product: {
    type: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Product',
      required: function () {
        return this.product.length > 0
      },
    }]
  },
```

The Event is being created anyway, and when I add no products, field product is an empty array.

Any idea how can I validate it?

Models:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Product = require('../models/Product');

const moment = require('moment');


const EventSchema = new Schema({

  client: {
    type: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Client'
    }]
  },

  product: {
    type: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Product',
      required: true
    }]
  },

  date: {
    type: Date,
    maxlength: 64,
    lowercase: true,
    trim: true
  },

  place: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 1200,
    minlength: 1,
  },

  price: {
    type: Number
  },

  comment: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 12000,
    minlength: 1,
  },

  status: {
    type: Number,
    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    default: 0,
    validate: {
      validator: Number.isInteger,
      message: '{VALUE} is not an integer value'
    }
  },
},
  {
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  },
);


const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Provider = require('./Provider')


const ProductSchema = new Schema({

  name: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 64,
    minlength: 1,
    required: [true, 'Product name is required'],
  },

  brand: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 64,
    minlength: 1,
  },

  description: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 12000,
    min: 1,
  },

  comment: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 12000,
    minlength: 1
  },

  state: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 64,
    minlength: 0
  },

  disponible: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  },

  price: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 999999
  },

  provider: {
    type: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Provider'
    }]
  },

  category: {
    type: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Category'
    }]
  },

  event: {
    type: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Event'
    }]
  },

  image: {
    type: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Image'
    }]
  },
},
  {
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [custom validators](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#custom-validators) feature of mongoose.

If the validator function returns undefined or a truthy value, validation succeeds. If it returns falsy (except undefined) or throws an error, validation fails.

```js
    product: {
      type: [
        {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "Product",
          required: true
        }
      ],
      validate: {
        validator: function(v) {
          return v !== null && v.length > 0;
        },
        message: props => "product is null or empty"
      }
    }
```

Now when you don't send product field, or send it empty array it will give validation error.

Comment: Thank you! worked perfectly. Could you please explain me briefly how is the validator working? Also in message, props returns me undefined...why?

Comment: @nacho you are welcome, I updated the answer with brief explanation.  I also updated  message function using a static message. In this scenario dynamic message is not very applicable, since props.value is null or empty array.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const notEmpty = function(users){
   if(users.length === 0){return false}
   else { return true }
 }

 const EventSchema = new Schema({
  product: {
    type: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Product',
      required: true,
      validate: [notEmpty, 'Please add at least one']
    }]
  }
})
```